# PHP gd extension missing from Google App Engine local Development Server

Tags: php, google-app-engine, drupal, gd

I've successfully been able to install Drupal onto GAE PHP (the real online one) but can't do so with the local Development Server of Google's App Engine because it complains the gd extension isn't enabled. I'm on OS X. Has anybody else found the gd extension missing or know of a way to enable it locally? Comparing the output from phpinfo() shows that indeed gd is only enabled on the production site, not locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bad news - There's a known bug in that the local development environment that is installed with the OS X SDK is missing the gd, zlib and mcrypt extensions. These **are** enabled in production.

The good news - if you want to simulate their use in your local development environment, you will need to install your own PHP interpreter through MacPorts, and use this in place of the built in one as follows.

```
sudo /opt/local/bin/port install php54-cgi php54-APC php54-calendar \
    php54-exif php54-gd php54-mysql php54-oauth php54-openssl php54-soap \
    php54-xdebug php54-xsl php54-mcrypt
```

After installation, the `php-cgi` (the binary used by the PHP SDK) can be found at `/opt/local/bin/php-cgi54`.

When starting the development server, you can then specify that it use this version of the php-cgi binary rather than the built in one using the `--php_executable` flag referencing the `php-cgi54` installed above.

Comment: FYI all, this bug has now been fixed in the latest SDK